# How to call one method globally across components in react native

Tags: react-redux, react-native

I have a method called submit() in one component like eg. leave.js.
I have declared all the router navigation in router.js component.
I have placed a button in leave component header which is in router.js to apply the leave. 
Now, i want to call this method from the click event of the button which is placed in the header.

How can i call this method globally from another component.

Kindly help me with a solution.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Janani

I have tried the below link but its not working for me.

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909

Answer (score 1):

When you create and use a function file, it's very useful.

**Example**

```js
let name = "name";

function setName(data) {
      name = data
}

function getName() {
   return name
}

export { setName, getName }
```

```js
import {setName, getName } from "./functionpath"

componentWilmount(){
   setName("John");
}

componentDidmount(){
   const name  = getName();
   alert(name);
}
```